# Cannot Use Custom Cursor

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am trying to use a custom cursor with a url code, but it seems that it will not work. Here is the link to the cursor I am trying to use: http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-detail/43903

Snippet:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=43903), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#8883;Featured&#8882;</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="walnutwetbar.html">Walnut Wetbar</a>
    <a href="woodandsteel.html">Wood and Steel</a>
    <a href="bluestainpine.html">Blue Stain Pine Changing Table</a>
    <a href="dualityguitar.html">Duality Guitar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super close, just add the word 'auto' at the end of cursor. 
IE:
cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=43903),auto;

https://jsfiddle.net/ttngcLgf/

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=43903),auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#8883;Featured&#8882;</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="walnutwetbar.html">Walnut Wetbar</a>
    <a href="woodandsteel.html">Wood and Steel</a>
    <a href="bluestainpine.html">Blue Stain Pine Changing Table</a>
    <a href="dualityguitar.html">Duality Guitar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Comment: @hannacreed mark Nathan's answer right - that's the best thanks you could give - unless he would rather prefer you send him a 6-pack of beer.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError haha, I tried to right after I used that code, but it told me I had to wait 2 minutes, and then I closed tab and forgot XD

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `, auto` after the image path you've specified for your custom cursor.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=43903), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#8883;Featured&#8882;</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="walnutwetbar.html">Walnut Wetbar</a>
    <a href="woodandsteel.html">Wood and Steel</a>
    <a href="bluestainpine.html">Blue Stain Pine Changing Table</a>
    <a href="dualityguitar.html">Duality Guitar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```